# Limit of a bounded differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

is it true that a continuously differentiable function $f: [0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that is bounded and $\|{f'(x)}\|\leq \frac{C}{x} 
\ \forall x \in [0,\infty)$ has limit for $x \rightarrow +\infty$ ?

Because it seems to me that it is true but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=\sin (\ln (1+x))$ is a counter-example. Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(e^{\frac {(2n+1)\pi} 2}-1)$ does not exist. The hypothesis holds with $C=1$.